# Изменение имени пользователя

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

хочу сделать изменение имени пользователя вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тоесть при нажимании на карандаш поле input меняет цвет фона, и разрешается редактирование. Но есть проблема, при загрузке сайта иконка карандаша, будет стоять в стороне так, как есть границы input. И хочется чтобы имя было видно полностью и при этом красиво всё это выглядело. Искал материал потому как подганять input под текст, но не нашел. Может есть метод получше, например всё организовать больше на JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать `padding-right` что-бы создать отступ внутри инпута справа
Поправка : вместо svg вы можете использовать тэг `i` с иконнкой из Font Awesome

```js
const name1 = document.getElementById("name1");
const name2 = document.getElementById("name2");
name1.addEventListener("keyup", changeLength1);
name2.addEventListener("keyup", changeLength2);

function changeLength1() {
  name1.setAttribute("size", name1.value.length - 3);
}

function changeLength2() {
  name2.setAttribute("size", name2.value.length - 3);
}

changeLength1();
changeLength2();
```

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  display: inline;
}

input {
  background-color: #fff;
}

#name1 {
  margin-right: 24px;
}

#name2 {
  padding-right: 24px;
}

input:nth-child(2) {
  padding-right: 24px;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  height: 80%;
  top: 10%;
  right: 5%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" id="name1" value="Nikolay">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
<path d="M362.7 19.32C387.7-5.678 428.3-5.678 453.3 19.32L492.7 58.75C517.7 83.74 517.7 124.3 492.7 149.3L444.3 197.7L314.3 67.72L362.7 19.32zM421.7 220.3L188.5 453.4C178.1 463.8 165.2 471.5 151.1 475.6L30.77 511C22.35 513.5 13.24 511.2 7.03 504.1C.8198 498.8-1.502 489.7 .976 481.2L36.37 360.9C40.53 346.8 48.16 333.9 58.57 323.5L291.7 90.34L421.7 220.3z"/>
</svg>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="text" id="name2" value="Nikolay">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
<path d="M362.7 19.32C387.7-5.678 428.3-5.678 453.3 19.32L492.7 58.75C517.7 83.74 517.7 124.3 492.7 149.3L444.3 197.7L314.3 67.72L362.7 19.32zM421.7 220.3L188.5 453.4C178.1 463.8 165.2 471.5 151.1 475.6L30.77 511C22.35 513.5 13.24 511.2 7.03 504.1C.8198 498.8-1.502 489.7 .976 481.2L36.37 360.9C40.53 346.8 48.16 333.9 58.57 323.5L291.7 90.34L421.7 220.3z"/>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Если у пользователя короткий ник, будет это выглядить не совсем красиво. Так как карандаш будет далеко от текста, я хочу чтобы он был прям возле конца текста

Comment: Обновил свой ответ

Comment: А как прикрепить вместо изображение карандаша, иконку Font Awesome?

Comment: Ещё поправка, два примера, икрнка внутри и скаружи